# How can I access the facebook books.reads's title using php?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

How can I to have access to the "title" or "id" of my books in /me/books.reads (via graph api explorer I can see it, but not fetch it for my app).

I,ve trying

`$books = $facebook->api('/me/book.reads','GET' );
foreach($books['data'] as $book) {
echo $book;
}`

but doesn't work.

What I need to do?

**UPDATE**

Using print_r ($book);

`Array ( [id] => 1404041189817636 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-11T05:23:56+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-11T05:23:56+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => Books [id] => 174275722710475 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 103118839728079 [url] => https://www.facebook.com/pages/O-alienista/103118839728079 [type] => books.book [title] => O alienista ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1402725673282521 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-08T12:06:56+0000 [end_time] => 2013-08-08T12:06:56+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-08T12:06:56+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => cultdynamo-alfa [namespace] => cultdynamoalfa [id] => 486466824776147 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 10151106849476668 [url] => http://samples.ogp.me/344468272304428 [type] => books.book [title] => Snow Crash ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1402724833282605 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-08T12:05:28+0000 [end_time] => 2013-08-08T12:05:28+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-08T12:05:28+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => cultdynamo-alfa [namespace] => cultdynamoalfa [id] => 486466824776147 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 10151106849476668 [url] => http://samples.ogp.me/344468272304428 [type] => books.book [title] => Snow Crash ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1402724089949346 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-08T12:02:20+0000 [end_time] => 2013-08-08T12:02:20+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-08T12:02:20+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => cultdynamo-alfa [namespace] => cultdynamoalfa [id] => 486466824776147 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 10151106849476668 [url] => http://samples.ogp.me/344468272304428 [type] => books.book [title] => Snow Crash ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1402724086616013 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-08T12:02:17+0000 [end_time] => 2013-08-08T12:02:17+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-08T12:02:17+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => cultdynamo-alfa [namespace] => cultdynamoalfa [id] => 486466824776147 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 10151106849476668 [url] => http://samples.ogp.me/344468272304428 [type] => books.book [title] => Snow Crash ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1402724056616016 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-08T12:02:05+0000 [end_time] => 2013-08-08T12:02:05+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-08T12:02:05+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => cultdynamo-alfa [namespace] => cultdynamoalfa [id] => 486466824776147 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 10151106849476668 [url] => http://samples.ogp.me/344468272304428 [type] => books.book [title] => Snow Crash ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1402246609997094 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-07T15:06:54+0000 [end_time] => 2013-08-07T15:06:54+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-07T15:06:54+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => cultdynamo-alfa [namespace] => cultdynamoalfa [id] => 486466824776147 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 10151106849476668 [url] => http://samples.ogp.me/344468272304428 [type] => books.book [title] => Snow Crash ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1402246209997134 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-07T15:05:16+0000 [end_time] => 2013-08-07T15:05:16+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-07T15:05:16+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => cultdynamo-alfa [namespace] => cultdynamoalfa [id] => 486466824776147 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 10151106849476668 [url] => http://samples.ogp.me/344468272304428 [type] => books.book [title] => Snow Crash ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1401338750087880 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-05T22:51:44+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-05T22:51:44+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => Books [id] => 174275722710475 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 10150941236166867 [url] => http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13583337-clube-da-luta [type] => good_reads:book [title] => Clube da Luta ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1400891206799301 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-05T02:57:48+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-05T02:57:48+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => Books [id] => 174275722710475 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 10150604461117511 [url] => http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6072069-cidade-de-deus [type] => good_reads:book [title] => Cidade De Deus ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1400890130132742 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-05T02:52:18+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-05T02:52:18+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => Books [id] => 174275722710475 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 108088695879860 [url] => https://www.facebook.com/pages/On-the-Road/108088695879860 [type] => books.book [title] => On the Road ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1400889916799430 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-05T02:51:27+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-05T02:51:27+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => Books [id] => 174275722710475 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 113172245363155 [url] => https://www.facebook.com/pages/Maus/113172245363155 [type] => books.book [title] => Maus ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) ) Array ( [id] => 1399682946920127 [from] => Array ( [name] => Inaldo Eleuterio [id] => 100006353053787 ) [start_time] => 2013-08-03T03:13:42+0000 [publish_time] => 2013-08-03T03:13:42+0000 [application] => Array ( [name] => Books [id] => 174275722710475 ) [data] => Array ( [book] => Array ( [id] => 108006402553308 [url] => https://www.facebook.com/pages/V-for-Vendetta/108006402553308 [type] => books.book [title] => V for Vendetta ) ) [type] => books.reads [no_feed_story] => [likes] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_like] => 1 [user_likes] => ) [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 [can_comment] => 1 [comment_order] => chronological ) )`

Comment: what does it output if you write `print_r($books);` ?

Comment: Hello, asifrc, thanks for comment. It's works, but returns a lot of useless data. How can I filter to show only title or id of the books read?

Comment: Can you post the result? Then we can be sure you're accessing it properly..

Comment: Ok, asifrc. It's a little longer, but you can I update the post.

Answer (score 0):

You were basically improperly accessing the array. Based on the structure of the array, here's how you can access the title and id of the books:

```
$books = $facebook->api('/me/book.reads','GET' );
foreach ($books as $book)
{
    echo "ID: ".$book['data']['book']['id'];
    echo "Title: ".$book['data']['book']['title'];
}
```

Let me know if this works and makes sense to you :)

Comment: hi, asifrc! sorry for my delay. when i tried your suggestion, the response was a blank page. so  i did one little reppair: `echo "Title: ".$book **['0']** ['data']['book']['title'];` now,  just one more ask: how can i access ['1'], ['2'] etc in the same command line?